# How do you say "Eggs are more dangerous than meat when it comes to superbacteria, because around 90% of antibiotics goes to chickens." in Latin?

Tags: contemporary-latin

> Ova sunt periculosiora quam carne sit de superbacteriis, quia circa 90% antibioticorum it gallis.
>
> [Reddit comment](https://www.reddit.com/r/latin/comments/vqj9bz/comment/ieydrsq/)

So, is that correct Latin?

Comment: Why the downvotes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several issues I see in this translation:

1. *aliquid it gallis*: this sounds too literal. In the first place, I don't think *eo* is quite right here as it sounds like something is moving; the idea however is that it arrives. Secondly, using *eo + dative* (gallis) is certainly not the usual way to go. *eo (in) + acc.* works better as L&S suggests.
2. *carne*: For comparison we can use the ablative of comparisons *or* use the *quam* formula. I think if we use *quam*, both sides should be in the same case. so as *ova* is the nominative, so the *caro* has to follow.
3. *sit de superbacteriis*: "when it comes to" can be translated more idiomatically as: *cum de aliqua re agitur*

Comment: I would add a couple of things.   First, the word order is too close to English word order.  This doesn't effect the literal syntax, but would render the pragmatics very strange.  I am not sure that "ōva" specifically presumes chicken eggs, as it does in contemporary English.  It might be better to specify "chicken eggs."

Comment: I’m not sure about Latin, but for a lot of modern languages, I wouldn’t translate “…goes to…” literally here — something closer to “…is given to…” would be more natural.